# Unable to access function in codeigniter library

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, object

New to PHP, oop & codeigniter.
My CI version is 3.1.2.

I am trying to load a library that I built, trying to understand Object oriented principles. Probably I'm missing something.

Below is my library.

```
<?php
class DPS {
    private $mode;

    public function __construct($params){
        //print_r($params);
        $this->mode = $params['mode'];
    }   

    public function get_url(){
        if($this->$mode == "TEST"){
            return "https://uat.paymentexpress.com/pxaccess/pxpay.aspx";
        } elseif($this->$mode == "LIVE"){
            return "https://sec.paymentexpress.com/pxaccess/pxpay.aspx";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I'm trying to access the get_url method in the controller below.

```
$params = [ 'mode' => 'TEST'];
$dps = $this->load->library('DPS',$params);     
echo $dps->get_url();
```

Codeigniter is throwing the below error message.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::get_url()

Being a newbie I'm probably missing some sort of OO fancy thingi. I just can't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$this->load->library('dps',$params);     
echo $this->dps->get_url();
```

Comment: Hi, I get "Message: Undefined variable: mode" error when I try that

Comment: oops, you should make small letters instead caps, while loading library, check my edited answer. @ElaBuwa

Comment: I get 2 errors. 1. Message: Undefined variable: mode -> pointed to the library. 2. Message: Cannot access empty property -> pointed to the library. All errors are pointed to the line that reads "if($this->$mode == "TEST"){"

Comment: change both lines that says `$this->$mode` to `$this->mode`

Answer (score 0):

Always load libraries in Codeigniter like this

```
$this->load->library('library_name');
```

And call to method of library using

```
$this->library_name->method_name();
```

SO try like this...

Save your library in `application/libraries` as `Dps.php`.Then

```
$params = [ 'mode' => 'TEST'];
$dps = $this->load->library('dps',$params);     
echo $this->dps->get_url();
```

And In your `DPS` library. Correct it

```
public function get_url(){
        if($this->mode == "TEST"){
            return "https://uat.paymentexpress.com/pxaccess/pxpay.aspx";
        } elseif($this->mode == "LIVE"){
            return "https://sec.paymentexpress.com/pxaccess/pxpay.aspx";
        }
    }
```